# Can spraying the car with a light layer of diesel help against corrosion?

Tags: physical-chemistry

I received an advice from a friend: put diesel in a bottle with a spray nozzle and spray the car with it. He said that this should form a layer on the car that helps against corrosion.

When I asked how he arrived at such a conclusion, he said that he saw an old corroded car, which was absolutely clean of corrosion where the fuel filler is.

Now, I understand that this is anecdotal evidence at best. However, I was considering if there might be any actual merit in following his advice? He suggested to spray the car once or twice a year (and has been doing so for his own car for a number of years now).

*I hope that this is the right forum for this question. If not, please kindly directly me to a more correct forum.*

Comment: Paint works better.

Comment: https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/ is probably a better forum for this question. Anyway, I'm pretty sure diesel can strip wax and tar off a vehicle. And you usually want that wax to protect the clearcoat and paint. Why protect the paint? Well, partly for looks, and long term for rust protection... Of course, non-painted surfaces would be a different consideration but there are specific undercoating products for that purpose.

Comment: The question should be: how much of the diesel you spray on your car evaporates and contributes directly to the greenhouse effect?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Corrosion (rust) is an oxidation reaction between the metal in the car body (iron) and oxygen, which is helped by the stability of the OH$^-$ species in water.  [Why can't rust form without water?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/5134/why-cant-rust-form-without-water)

So anything that prevents water from interacting with the surface will reduce corrosion.  Diesel, a liquid hydrocarbon, can be such a barrier.  I don't doubt that an area continuously exposed to fuel leaks would be less corroded than other areas.  Of course that doesn't mean it's a good idea to just throw fuel all over your car.

Diesel is much less volatile than gasoline/petrol, but it still evaporates, and it's thin enough to run off surfaces.  Besides the hazards involved with using it as something other than a fuel, I can't imagine that it would remain a useful barrier for very long, let alone a year.

Automobile waxes and sealers would presumably be chosen to be less hazardous, less toxic, and longer useful barrier performance than diesel.

Comment: Another thing that he said: diesel helps to remove the rust, since it is liquid enough to penetrate the tiny cracks that contain rust. My question is: is this true, and if true, are there better alternatives for acheiving the same effect?

Comment: That would be a better question on chemistry or motor vehicle SE.  But I suspect the first part is that no it can't "remove" rust.